# Problem parsing a table from html using BeautifulSoup and saving it as a csv

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://pqt.cbp.gov/report/YYZ_1/12-01-2017')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r)
table = soup.find('table', attrs={ "class" : "table-horizontal-line"})
headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]
rows = []
for row in table.find_all('tr'):
    rows.append([val.text.encode('utf8') for val in row.find_all('td')])

with open('output_file.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(row for row in rows if row)
```

I am trying to parse all table data in this particular webpage: https://pqt.cbp.gov/report/YYZ_1/12-01-2017

I am getting an error in the line `soup = BeautifulSoup(r)`. I get an error `TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()`. I am also not sure if my logic is correct. Plz help me pasing the table data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way

```
import pandas as pd
result = pd.read_html("https://pqt.cbp.gov/report/YYZ_1/12-01-2017")
df = result[0]
# df = df.drop(labels='Unnamed: 8', axis=1)
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8',index = False )
```

Comment: After u made the edit, the output file does not appear without an error. You were dropping the last row, right?

Comment: The last column

Comment: But simply exclude the 4th line above

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
r = requests.get('https://pqt.cbp.gov/report/YYZ_1/12-01-2017')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)
```

Comment: Now I get an error on `headers = [header.text for header in table.find_all('th')]`
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all''`

Answer (score 0):

variable `r` is type `Response` not `str`, use `r.text` or `r.content` and there are no table with class `table-horizontal-line`, do you mean `results` ?

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
table = soup.find('table', attrs={"class" : "results"})
```